# Error in Multilevel Textview

Tags: java, android

I have added an `ExpandableListview` within another `ExpandableListview`.
I have added 2 `TextView` only, but I am getting four `TextView` instead of two.

Image:

[image]

Can anyone suggest  something to me?

Comment: share your code as well , if you can

Comment: Use the {} option in the editor to include code , or add external file attachment

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your adapter:

```
@Override
    public ing getChildrenCount(int groupPosition){
         return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to be able to help you without seeing your code, but it's likely that you pass 4 `TextView`s into your `Adapter` by accident from your `Activity`.

`MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(TextViewArray, getContext())`

where `TextViewArray` has 4 `TextView`s in it.

This would be backed up by whether your `getGroupCount()` in your Adapter is returning the proper size of the array you passed.

```
public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }
```